What movie is this quote from? "We're new in town, and we've never had sex before!"
This has been bugging me all day.. I think it was an 80s/highschool movie.. I don't think it was Fast Times or The Wild Life, seems too racy for Back to the Future. Could it have been Grease?
I think this is the context: Some guys are talking outside at night, a car (convertible?) with girls drives by and shouts, "We're new in town, and we've never had sex before!" (or something to that effect), and a couple of the guys hop in their car and follow 'em.

Johnny Be Good, (1988), with Anthony Michael Hall, Robert Downey Jr., and Uma Thurman.  The clip with that line is here.

God bless your soul.
